# Url order for sitemap generating

Tags: xml, laravel, sitemap

Are the urls in the website http://dev.american-contractor.com in correct format in order to generate a google friendly sitemap?

Comment: What do you mean by *urls in the website*?

Comment: I mean the navigation links